# jetty9 in open suse: how to start?

Tags: java, jetty, opensuse

I installed jetty via gwt maven plugin and it works in development mode.
Then I want to deploy.. hm... I did with tomcat, but it is stupid to have two servers run.

So I try with jetty also for production.

So I tried to figure out how to start jetty.

Unfortunately all advise seems old.
In suse tumbleweed jetty is split into modules.
I tried to install the start module and to start with `java -jar jetty-start.jar`.

Answer:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/ManifestUtils
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartArgs.<clinit>(StartArgs.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:292)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.ManifestUtils
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        ... 3 more

Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information
```

Ok, i am in `/usr/share/java/jetty` which may be `JETTY_HOME`,
but instead of `start.jar`, there is only `jetty-start.jar`.
Do I have to install another module?
Or am I in a completely wrong folder???

Help very much appreciated.